# Is it normal that Flutter integration tests takes long time to start (Gradle task takes between 45s-120s)

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-android, flutter-integration-test

When I start my `integration_test` in flutter it takes Gradle something between 45s to 120s to complete (I don't really know why it varies so much).

Even if I run simplest UI test that takes few seconds to complete, this waiting for Gradle to complete is huge waste of time. Is it normal?

My output console:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             49.4s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...              1,300ms
✓ ONBOARDING TESTS GROUP open app for first time and see onboarding
Exited
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it works.